# Javascript Protractor - Is there any solution to run protractor test with remote node_modules?

Tags: protractor

I'm writing automation test for the angularjs web app. Using protractor and cucumber. 
From beginning, I organized the test as a separate folder and actually it required different node packages from the root project(the project built up the web app).

Today there's a requirement that the node_modules of test project should be merged with the node_modules of root project. 
As per my knowledge, when running the command protractor protractor_conf.js, the system looks for the node_modules in 1 level upstream folder.

I'm attaching the screenshot of my project folder to be clearer.

[image: Current project oganization]

Appreciate all suggestions !
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will not recommend you not to save node_modules as the separate folder in the project directory. Instead, you can create a `package.json` file for your test project and list all the dependencies in the package.json file. so each time before you run `protractor conf.js` ,just run `npm install` command from the directory where your project is available. So by doing this way will help you to run the e2e scripts in different machines without depending on the `node_modules` folder.

[Example package.json for protractor](https://markcoleman.silvrback.com/getting-started-with-protractor)

Also, it is advisable to maintain separate `node_modules` for different project because it may avoid versions conflicts of any node_module that is used in both projects.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. 
Actually all required packages for the test are included in the package.json file.
I really appreciate the point "to avoid version conflict"

But is there any solution to run the test scripts with the remote node_modules as per my question ?

Comment: Then why yo need to merge node_modules for two different projects? Are you going to chek in your code into any svn like git?

Comment: Yes, the test project is supposed to be pushed to bitbucket. 
The idea is to optimize the project folder to have only 1 node_modules folder for both Dev and Test.
I agree that there may be version conflict. But I still want to know whether there's such solution for protractor to run with remote node_modules folder.